# VideoCapture from sequence with int64 names starting from specific file

Tags: python, opencv, video, sequence

I have a sequence of images that are named with int64 timestamps. I also have a specific timestamp where I would like to start the VideoCapture.

#### Problem 1

```py
cv2.VideoCapture('./%19d.png', cv2.CAP_IMAGES)
```

doesn't work.
I've done the following tests (with sequence names adjusted accordingly)

```py
cv2.VideoCapture('./%019d.png', cv2.CAP_IMAGES) # doesn't work
cv2.VideoCapture('./%10d.png', cv2.CAP_IMAGES) # doesn't work
cv2.VideoCapture('./%010d.png', cv2.CAP_IMAGES) # doesn't work
cv2.VideoCapture('./%09d.png', cv2.CAP_IMAGES) # works
cv2.VideoCapture('./%9d.png', cv2.CAP_IMAGES) # works
```

The problem seems that the cv2 format specifier doesn't take 2 digit lengths. Is there some syntax I haven't tried yet or is this a limitation of opencv?

#### Problem 2

I would also like to start the VideoCapture at a specific frame. I can get the specific timestamp, or the N:th frame that I would like to start from. However I'm not at liberty to make any changes to the filesystem.

Even something like giving `cv2.VideoCapture` a sequence of filenames, which I can prepare in python would work, but I cant find any indications if that is possible.

Comment: just imread them individually. -- if you find the format string issue sufficiently annoying, feel free to open an issue on opencv's github. perhaps skim this code to find where the issue could be: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp#L221 that part seems to be input validation, so needs to be extended just a little (`if` to `while` and it's done)

Comment: no @toyotaSupra that is python syntax. OpenCV will not understand that. why would you even suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Overall workaround: just `imread` your list of pictures individually. `VideoCapture` does little more than that.

Problem 1: requires a tiny change to the input validation in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp#L221, namely replacing `if` to be `while`. This is makes the validation more forgiving than it needs to be (accepts arbitrary-digit format widths, instead of just 1-digit) but ehhhh it'll be fine.

Problem 2: you might be able to use `cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` though I've never done that with `CAP_IMAGES`. If that doesn't work, it is supposed to, and would be worth opening an issue on OpenCV's github.

NB: be careful with multiple problems in the same question. This site prefers one problem per question.